# simple strpos() not working with "[" char, why?

Tags: php, strpos

why does if i do:

```
if(strpos("[","[rgeger]")){ 
echo 'hey'; 
}
```

it doesn't prints anything?

try this with a string:

```
function return_tags($keywords){
 if($keywords){
  $k_array = array();

  foreach($this->check($keywords) as $key=>$value){

    array_push($k_array, $value);
  }

  $last_array = array();
  foreach($k_array as $key=>$value){
    if(strpos("[", $value) && strpos("]", $value) && strlen($value) >= 2){
      $value = '<span class="tag">'.$value.'</span>';

    }
    array_push($last_array, trim($value));

  }
  return $last_array;

 }else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

string example

```
  $keywords = "freignferi eiejrngirj erjgnrit [llll] [print me as tag]";
```

did you see any `<span>` element printed in html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you swapped the arguments:

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

So if you want to know if a `[` is in your string `[rgeger]`:

```
if (strpos("[rgeger]", "[") !== false) { 
  echo 'hey'; 
}
```

(Source: http://php.net/strpos)

Comment: damn english is my problem don't know the meaning of haystack and needle and i inverted them :/

Answer (score 3):

The position returned is zero-indexed, so the first character is at position 0. When evaluating 0 as Boolean, it's false - so it doesn't get into the block.

Fix with this:

```
if (strpos('[rgeger]', '[') !== false)
```

**Also** the arguments are the wrong way round. Don't upvote this post any more; go upvote robbi's instead for spotting that one :) Eagle eyes robbi, EAGLE eyes :P

Comment: Edit: Humble pie. Go see robbi's answer, he's got it :)

Comment: i've no idea how this php thing works. but this comparison compares an int with a boolean right? that looks a bit weird. what's the intention of that comparison?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb PHP is lazy. If you say "Is this integer the same as that false?" it'll say "Aha! I can't compare int to bool, let's convert the bool TO an int (or the other way round) and then compare it". You can force a type and value comparison by using `===` instead of `==`, making if checking that it's (a) boolean and (b) false, rather than just 'falsey'

Comment: you followed me, but i inverted arguments and you too %)

Answer (score 2):

Because you have to check the return value of `strpos()` as it could be zero because `[` it's at index zero, and zero evaluates to FALSE that's why it wouldn't enter your if block, so check that the return value it's FALSE and type boolean, not just integer zero, like this:

```
if(strpos("[rgeger]","[") !== false){ 
  echo 'hey'; 
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The parameters were in wrong order too, the subject string comes first then the search string, I updated my code above to reflect that.

Comment: You also had the parameters wrongly , the subject string comes first then the search string, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because its wrong. [Strpos](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php) give false if the condition is false.

```
if(strpos("[rgeger]","[") !== false){ 
    echo 'hey'; 
}
```

Edit: I have corrected my answer. Your parameter are in the wrong order. Its:

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because actually strpos can return 0 see [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

> **Warning**
>   This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

So you have to compare with the `false`value directly.

```
if(strpos("[","[rgeger]") !== false){ 
  echo 'hey'; 
}
```

**EDIT ::**

Careful.. Look at the arguments order

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

Haystack is the string input.
Needle is what you are seeking for.

```
if(strpos("[regeger]","[") !== false){ 
  echo 'hey'; 
}
```